# I need simple example to use combobox in datagrid(MVV

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagrid

I'm newbie in wpf, mvvm sort of things.
I was trying to make wpf application like this.
[image]

but what the trying is like this below.

[image]

I cannot find how to use combobox in datagrid.
I googled about so much about but i coludn't find it.

Please simple example how to use combobox in datagrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the "DataGridComboBoxColumn" column.

Here an example:
**XAML**

```
<DataGrid Name="myGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
 <DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text" Binding="{Binding Name}">    
  </DataGridTextColumn>
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Combobox" x:Name="ComboboxColumn" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding City}">
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**XAML.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
string[] Cities = new string[]{ "MI", "MN", "LA" };
List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();
Persons.Add(new Person { Name="Person 1", City= "MI" });
Persons.Add(new Person { Name = "Person 2", City = "MN" });

InitializeComponent();

ComboboxColumn.ItemsSource = Cities;
myGrid.ItemsSource = Persons;
}

   public class Person { 
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string City { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but if there's a way to add diifferent combobox in datagrid? i want to add different combobox in datagrid row...